# Htaccess in cordova webapp

Tags: android, .htaccess, cordova, web, hosted

I'm running an hosted webapp via cordova. Now I protected the webapp with htaccess. On osx it works as desired. On android the authentication dialog does not appear and the webapp responds to a bad login.

Does somebody know how why the dialog gets blocked? And how to ged rid of this problem?

I've used the cordova-plugin-whitelist to allow the navigation to the webapp.